# How to change the packages.config location when installing a NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

After following [Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) . . . so in Visual Studio I deleted all NuGet references from all the .csproj files in a multi-project solution and I also deleted the files:

.nuget/NuGet.exe
.nuget/Nuget.targets

and only kept:

.nuget/NuGet.Config

Then in the Package Manager Console, trying to install a package:

```
PM> Get-Project myProject | Install-Package somePackage -Version 1.0
```

results in a "successful installation," but a reference isn't being added to the References node for myProject

[image]

and the packages.config is being created in:

.nuget/packages.config

and not in:

myProject/packages.config

How can I change the installation location so that NuGet will install in the root of myProject?

**NOTE using:**
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50926.663
Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Comment: What NuGet package are you installing? Solution only NuGet packages will update the .nuget/NuGet.Config file and not add anything to the project packages.config file.

Comment: I am installing a package from a local feed. So how do you install a package into a specific project and not into the solution?

Comment: Most packages will install into a project. A few will install into a solution since they are solution only packages. One example is a OpenCover which will not install into a project. Which NuGet package are you installing? There is no NuGet setting which affects which packages.config file is updated. It just depends on the package you are installing - whether it is a solution only package or not.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was mistakenly creating and installing solution-level packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Ward, I found the problem. I was mistakenly creating and installing a solution-level package. This was because I was not adding the dll to the lib folder when creating nuget packages using [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/).

[image]

More info can be found here:

[Creating a solution-level package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)
A solution-level package is one that installs a tool or additional commands for the Package Manager console, but does not add references, content, or build customizations to any projects in your solution. For example, the psake package installs Powershell scripts you can use to automate your build process.

A package is considered a solution-level package if it does not contain any files in its lib, content, or build directories. If the package has dependencies, they also must not have files in their lib, content, or build directories.
When a solution-level package is installed, it is tracked in a packages.config file in the .nuget directory, rather than in a packages.config file in a specific project.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of installing a package through package manager console is this:

**Syntax:**

`Install-Package [-Id] <string> [-IgnoreDependencies] [-ProjectName <string>] [-Version <string>] [-Source <string>] [-IncludePrerelease] [-Force] [-FileConflictAction] [-DependencyVersion <dependencyVersion>] [-WhatIf]`

To install a package in a particular project you have to use the following command:

`PM> Install-Package somePackage -Project myProject`

If you omit the `-Project` parameter the default project (from the drop-down) is chosen.

Comment: PM> Install-Package somePackage -Project myProject doesn't work. It is still installing in the .nuget folder. Is there a NuGet setting that is causing this?